# Hudson -- windows slave running a shell script

Tags: windows, continuous-integration, hudson, msys, master-slave

I am trying to run a shell script lets call it fml.sh on my windows slave machine.

I have installed msys. I can run the script from cmd with the following call.

```
C:\msys\1.0\bin\sh.exe -e -x "C:\path\to\fml.sh"
```

Now in my build pre-build code I run that very same line from within hudson I get the following response.

```
AllocationBase 0x71590000, BaseAddress 0x715B0000, RegionSize 0x38000, State 0x1000
C:\msys\1.0\bin\sh.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 487
```

My mind is boggled, and very much bothered.

Does anyone else know of a way to run a script on a windows slave from within Hudson.

Very same thing happens with bash.exe as well.

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a link [online](http://old.nabble.com/****-Couldn't-reserve-space-for-cygwin's-heap,-Win32-error-6-td28809741.html) that says that the problem can be resolved by running the following:

```
$ rebase -b 0x30000000 msys-1.0.dll
```

I haven't tried it but I am hopeful.

Edit: this is confirmed and solved my problem. I had to do a bit of googling to get the rebase.exe

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cygwin, rebasing is an issue that can affect many dll's so you might need to rebase more dlls. This [link](http://cygwin.wikia.com/wiki/Rebaseall) explains simple steps to rebase all dlls and also has an explanation why it happens.